# Is it possible to run a test-case in a TestNG suite only after the previous test-case is completely executed?

Tags: automated-tests, testng

I have a Testng testsuite containing a few testcases like : -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Regression" parallel="false">
  <test name="Automation">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.xxx.automation.testcases.xxxTest"/>
      <class name="com.xxx.automation.testcases.yyyTest"/>
      <class name="com.xxx.automation.testcases.zzzTest"/>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

When I run the testsuite I see 3 instances of the browser running the 3 test cases in parallel. As you can see I have specified

> parallel = "false"

I am required to run the testcases serially in such a manner that a test case will run only after the previous one is completed.
Is this possible? If yes how?

Comment: completely you mean all test pass ?

Comment: @shutdown-hnow: I want to run xxxTest - finish it - then yyyTest and so on. 
Handling both pass and fail.

Answer (score 0):

you can try two [more] versions:

```
 <suite name="TestCase" parallel="false">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="suite1.xml"/>
    <suite-file path="suite2.xml"/>
    <suite-file path="suite3.xml"/>
 </suite-files>
</suite>
```

where: suite1,2,3 looks :

```
<suite name="Reg_1" parallel="false">
  <test name="Test_1">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.xxx.automation.testcases.1Test"/>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

OR

```
<suite name="Reg_All" parallel="false">
  <test name="T1">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.xxx.automation.testcases.1Test"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
  <test name="T2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.xxx.automation.testcases.2Test"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="T3">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.xxx.automation.testcases.3Test"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```